# UNIX Grep Function

Tags: sorting, unix, grep, cut, uniq

I have a file with tab-separated columns. I want to calculate the unique entries within a column. However, I want to calculate the unique based on only the enter in the column and remove any subsequent markers within the brackets.

The table looks like this:

```
1 abc def xxx(sd) 5677
2 ddd hhh yyy(dd) 4321
3 fds ggf xxx(df) 5666
```

Now I want to calculate the unique number of times `xxx` and `yyy` are calculated

So the expected output should be `2`, while I get `3`.

The code that i used is :

```
cut -f4 f.txt| sort| uniq -D |wc -l
```

Comment: Note that `sort` has a `-k` option that allows you to sort by a specified portion of the input, removing the need to `cut` the input first.

Comment: I don't see how that would give 3. When I run it, after correcting the `cut` command, is 0 because the fourth column is unique for all rows.

Comment: The number of characters in the column based on which unique entries are to be calculated can vary. So i want to calculate all possible entries as long as they are unique.

Comment: the initial number is also a column

Answer (score 2):

Standard debugging technique: Go single-step, check intermediate output.

With `cut -f4` you are taking the fourth field, which in this case is:

```
xxx(sd)
yyy(dd)
xxx(df)
```

That's three distinct entries, no matter how you sort them.

Elaborating on my comment regarding the `-k` option of `sort`, this gives the expected "2". (I'm not sure what you're doing with the `-D` option to `uniq`.)

```
sort -k4.1,4.3 -u f.txt | wc -l
```

`-k4.1,4.3` means "sort by the 1st through 3rd character of the 4th field", the `-u` means "list unique lines only", resulting in:

```
1   abc def xxx(sd) 5677
2   ddd hhh yyy(dd) 4321
```

The second `xxx` line is not distinct and does not get listed.

---

**EDIT**:

Alternatively, you could extract the desired part of the input line using `sed`, and feeding *that* to `sort -u | wc -l`. I still haven't fully understood the specs of your input, so I'm still guessing here:

```
sed "s/\(\S\+\s\+\)\{3\}\([^(]\+\).*/\2/" f.txt
```

Explained:

- `\S\+\s\+` - 1..n non-whitespaces followed by 1..n whitespaces...
- `\(\S\+\s\+\)\{3\}` - ...repeated three times...
- `\([^(]\+\)` - ... followed by 1..n characters that are not `(`...
- `.*` - ...followed by anything...
- `/\2/` - ...replace by whatever matched the second group (1..n characters that are not `(`).

This gives:

```
xxx
yyy
xxx
```

Comment: but what i want is that it should tell me that xxx and yyy has been unique and not make a bracket condition as part of unique thing.

Comment: for eg: cut -f4 gave  me xxx(sd) yyy(dd) xxx(df) xx(gg) yyz(rd)... Now i want to find out how many unique xxx, yyy, xx, yyz are there. Am not concerned with brackets and i just want the number of times the values ahead of the brackets are repeated.

Comment: @Ankur: Sorry but I have problems understanding your intention. As far as I can tell, my answer does *exactly* what you're asking for. Added some explanation to make it more clear.

Comment: @Ankur: Added alternative using `sed`. You should be able to adapt one of the two solutions to your needs.

Comment: The input could be of 2 characters folowed by bracket or 6 characters followed by brakcet. So it could be xx(ds) or be zzzzzz(hh)

Comment: @Ankur: Then the `sed` variant is the way to go, because AFAIK you cannot make either `cut` or `sort` to separate fields at *both* tabulator and bracket, which would be what you'd need to make your format work. If you can assert that the bracket in the fourth column is actually the only the first in the record, you can do the simpler `sed "s/.*\s\([^(]\+\).*/\2/" f.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, you can also try with this, which will give you count how many times something was repeated (xxx and yyy):

```
cat test.txt | awk {'print substr($4,0,4)'} | sort | uniq --count
```

And if you need only the number of different, just add `wc -l`, like so

```
cat test.txt | awk {'print substr($4,0,4)'} | sort | uniq --count | wc -l
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: @Ankur: Judging from your comment to my answer, this `awk` will fail you as soon as there are less or more than 3 characters before the bracket. You *need* to specify *precisely* the possible input, *then* come up with the proper extraction of what you want to count. Trial & error isn't going to cut it.

Comment: Note that `cat file | awk '...'` can be rewritten to `awk '...' file`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of times every block appears with:

```
$ awk -F"[ (]" '{a[$4]++} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
xxx 2
yyy 1
```

#### Explanation

- `-F"[ (]"` sets field separator as space or `(`.
- `{a[$4]++}` keeps track of how many times the 4th field appears (based on those field separators, that is `xxx`, `yyy`...).
- `END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}` prints the results.

---

If you are just concerned about which different values you can use:

```
$ awk -F"[ (]" '{a[$4]} END {for (i in a) print i}' file
xxx
yyy
```

#### Explanation

- `-F"[ (]"` sets field separator as space or `(`.
- `{a[$4]}` keeps track of which 4th field appears (based on those field separators, that is `xxx`, `yyy`...).
- `END {for (i in a) print i}` prints the results without the counter.